# Multiple Appointment/Meeting options in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, appointments

I am wanting to know if there is a way to send someone in Outlook 2 appointment options and let them pick which one they want, which would automatically decline the other option.

The only way I can do this is to send two completely separate meeting appointment invitations, and they would have to Accept the desired one and Decline the other. To me this introduces the human problem of accidentally accepting/declining both or accepting one and then having to assume that is correct and the other was declined.

I wasn't sure what to search for or how to word what I'm trying to do into a query. I am using Microsoft Outlook 2010 without Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/create-a-pick-a-meeting-request/

See if this is the information you are looking for.  I was researching this question myself and came across your question.